# SQL: how to randomly sample a number of values for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop

Suppose I have a table `A (id string)`, what I need is to create a table `B (id1 string, id2 string)` such that, `B.id2` is randomly sampled from `A.id`. `B.id1` is the same as `A.id`. For example:

table `A`:

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

table `B`:

```
id1   id2
 1     2
 1     3
 2     4
 2     3
 3     1
 3     2
 4     1
 4     4
```

That is, for each `id` in `A`, randomly sample 2 `id` in `A` as a new column `id2`. How can I do this with SQL? I would prefer a sample without replacement. But it is ok if `id2` equals `id1`. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Did you check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx?

Comment: @pfc table B is your expected result .?

Comment: @Sahathulla Yes.

Comment: mysql or sql-server ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze In fact I'm using it on Hadoop. But any solution is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is this:

```
 select  id as id1, (select id from A order by rand() limit 1) as id2 from A  
 union all
 select  id as id1, (select id from A order by rand() limit 1) as id2 from A
```

you can use `insert into ... select ...` for put this values into table B.

If you want more than  2 id's, for example several dozens, then this method is bad choice.

Comment: Yes. But it will be inefficient if I want to make an arbitrary number of samples for each row. The 2 is merely a toy example.

Comment: @pfc . . . This answers the question that you asked.

Comment: I would take your answer. But I have to say this is not the whole thing that I expect. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to do a `cross join` and then take random rows.  For instance:

```
select a1.id, a2.id
from A a1 cross join
     A a2
where a1.id <> a2.id and
      rand() <= 0.01;
```

This would be relatively efficient.  It would pull roughly 1% of the rows from the cross join.  You wouldn't be guaranteed the same number of rows for each id.

If you needed to get the same number for each id, you could extend this idea using variables:

```
select id1, id2
from (select a1.id as id1, a2.id as id2,
             (@rn := if(@i = a1.id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := a1.id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from A a1 cross join
           A a2 cross join
           (select @i := -1, @rn := 0) params
      where a1.id <> a2.id 
      order by a1.id, rand()
     ) aa
where rn <= 2;
```

This will not have very good performance characteristics.  It should work okay on a table with up to a thousand rows or so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (done in SQL Server):

```
SELECT ID FROM TableA ORDER By ID

OPEN CURA

FETCH NEXT FROM CURA
INTO @id1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--fetch 2 rows casually from same table, different from the first column
DECLARE CURB CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE ID <> @id1 ORDER BY NEWID()

OPEN CURB

FETCH NEXT FROM CURB INTO @id2
INSERT INTO @TempTable(ID1, ID2) VALUES (@id1, @id2)
FETCH NEXT FROM CURB INTO @id2
INSERT INTO @TempTable(ID1, ID2) VALUES (@id1, @id2)

CLOSE CURB
DEALLOCATE CURB

FETCH NEXT FROM CURA
INTO @id1

END

CLOSE CURA
DEALLOCATE CURA

SELECT * from @TempTable ORDER BY ID1, ID2
```

If you want a different number of rows for each group, simply substitute the two FETCH NEXT FROM CURB with a counted loop